# Update layout in pysimplegui by selecting from menu

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have this very simple gui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def fun1(data):
    return data * 2


def fun2(data):
    return data + 2


def fun3(data):
    return data ** 2


def main():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Select function'), sg.OptionMenu(
            values=('fun1', 'fun2', 'fun3'), default_value='fun1')],
        [sg.Text("Enter your input:"), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Exit()],
        [sg.Output(size=(50, 10), key='-OUTPUT-')]
    ]

    window = sg.Window("My GUI", layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Exit"):
            break

        selected_function = values[0]
        user_input = values[1]

        try:
            user_input = int(user_input)
            if selected_function == 'fun1':
                result = fun1(user_input)
            elif selected_function == 'fun2':
                result = fun2(user_input)
            elif selected_function == 'fun3':
                result = fun3(user_input)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Invalid function selected.")

            window['-OUTPUT-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(result)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")

    window.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now I want to change the label "Enter your input" next to user input to something else when function2 is selected from the drop down menu or even add a second input if function2 requires two arguments.

I have tried with layout.update() but I cannot trigger an event when I select something from the drop down menu.

I can achieve what I want by adding a button "Update".

Are pressing buttons the only way to trigger an event in pysimplegui?

Comment: The element typically used for "Drop Down" lists is the `Combo` element.  You can use `enable_events` with this element to get an event when an item is chosen.  Setting `readonly=True` will cause the behavior to be similar to the `OptionMenu` Element (you can't type in your own option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option `enable_events` for OptionMenu to generate event, so you cannot trigger the function to do your job.

I built one last year by tkinter code for it.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def callback(var, index, mode):
    """
    For OptionMenu
    var - tkinter control variable.
    index - index of var, '' if var is not a list.
    mode - 'w' for 'write' here.
    """
    window.write_event_value("Option", window['Option'].TKStringVar.get())


def fun1(data):
    return data * 2


def fun2(data):
    return data + 2


def fun3(data):
    return data ** 2


def main():

    global window

    function = {"x 2":fun1, "+ 2":fun2, "** 2":fun3}
    lst = list(function.keys())
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Select function'),
         sg.OptionMenu(values=lst, default_value=lst[0], key='Option')],
        [sg.Text("Enter your input:"),
         sg.InputText(key='IN')],
        [sg.Button("Submit"),
         sg.Exit()],
        [sg.Output(size=(50, 10), key='-OUTPUT-')]
    ]

    window = sg.Window("My GUI", layout, finalize=True)
    window['Option'].TKStringVar.trace("w", callback)

    while True:

        event, values = window.read()

        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Exit"):
            break

        elif event == "Option":
            selected_function = values[event]
            user_input = values["IN"]
            try:
                user_input = int(user_input)
            except ValueError:
                sg.popup("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
                continue
            if selected_function in function:
                result = function[selected_function](user_input)
            else:
                sg.popup("Invalid function selected.")
            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(f'{user_input} {selected_function} = {result}')

    window.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your function is exactly what I wanted. I just changed it a bit to work in a multitab gui. Thank you.