# Add and remove elements with pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

With the help of Jason Yang ([Update layout in pysimplegui by selecting from menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76914162/update-layout-in-pysimplegui-by-selecting-from-menu)) I was able to trigger an event by selecting from a drop down menu. Now I can add another user input for a function that needs two positional arguments.
My only problem is in appearance. I use visible=False or True to hide or show the second input and when I hide it the space it used to occupy remains there.
Is there any better way to add and remove elements?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def callback(var, index, mode):
    """
    For OptionMenu
    var - tkinter control variable.
    index - index of var, '' if var is not a list.
    mode - 'w' for 'write' here.
    """
    window.write_event_value("Option", window['Option'].TKStringVar.get())


def fun1(data):
    return data ** 2


def fun2(base, exponent):
    return base**exponent


def main():

    global window

    function = {"x**2": fun1, "x**y": fun2}
    lst = list(function.keys())
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Select function'),
         sg.OptionMenu(values=lst, default_value=lst[0], key='Option')],
        [sg.Column(
            [[sg.Text("Enter a number"), sg.InputText(size=(20, 1), key='base')]])],
        [sg.Column([[sg.Text("Enter exponent"), sg.InputText(
            size=(20, 1), key='exponent')]], key='exponent-row', visible=False)],
        [sg.Button("Submit"),
         sg.Exit()],
        [sg.Output(size=(50, 10), key='-OUTPUT-')]
    ]

    window = sg.Window("My GUI", layout, finalize=True)
    window['Option'].TKStringVar.trace("w", callback)

    while True:

        event, values = window.read()

        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Exit"):
            break

        elif event == "Option":
            selected_function = values[event]
            # user_input = values["IN"]
            if selected_function == 'x**y':
                window[('exponent-row')].update(visible=True)
            else:
                window[('exponent-row')].update(visible=False)
        elif event == 'Submit':
            try:
                user_input = int(values['base'])
                selected_function = values['Option']
            except ValueError:
                sg.popup("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
                continue
            if selected_function == 'x**2':
                result = function[selected_function](user_input)
            elif selected_function == 'x**y':
                exp = int(values['exponent'])
                result = function[selected_function](user_input, exp)
            else:
                sg.popup("Invalid function selected.")
            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(
                f'Result = {result}')

    window.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Use the `pin` layout helper function so the location shrinks. [This Demo Program](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Invisible_Elements_Pinning.py) shows how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. 

But since I'm doing all this just for learning, I still wonder if there is a different approach to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my comment as an answer....

Use the `pin` layout helper function so the location shrinks. This [Demo Program](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Invisible_Elements_Pinning.py) shows how to use it.

Since the Demo Program is short, here's the code that demonstrates using the `pin` function.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    Demo - "Pinning" an element into a location in a layout
    
     
    Copyright 2020, 2022, 2023 PySimpleGUI
"""

layout = [  [sg.Text('Hide Button or Multiline. Buttons 1 & 2 hide Button 2')],
            [sg.pin(sg.Multiline(size=(60, 10), key='-MLINE-'))],
            [sg.pin(sg.Button('Button1')), sg.pin(sg.Button('Button2'), shrink=False), sg.B('Toggle Multiline')],
        ]

window = sg.Window('Visible / Invisible Element Demo', layout)

toggle = toggle_in = False
while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if event in ('Button1', 'Button2'):
        window['Button2'].update(visible=toggle)
        toggle = not toggle
    elif event == 'Toggle Multiline':
        window['-MLINE-'].update(visible=not window['-MLINE-'].visible)
window.close()
```